# In Windows 8, can you disable the new network connections sidebar and restore the classic connection dialog?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8

Windows 8 introduced a sidebar for connecting to network connections such as VPNs, as shown in the screenshot below.

Is it possible to get rid of this sidebar and restore the normal Windows 7 style network connection dialog box?

I want the old Windows 7 connection dialog again.

Screenshot of Windows 8 sidebar connection:

[image]

Screenshot of Windows 7 dialog box:

[image]

Comment: search for `Set up a virtual private network (VPN) connection` that will allow you to use the legacy method to configure a VPN.

Comment: @Ramhound That is only for setting it up - it doesn't allow you to enter username/password each time you want to connect.